# Modismo o expresión en español para "twinsies"

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones, humor

Hoy ha dado la casualidad de que dos miembros de mi equipo han venido con la misma camisa. No es la primera vez que pasa, y otro miembro del equipo decía que él tiene también la misma camisa.

Hay personas a las que les molesta mucho que otra persona vaya con la misma ropa que ellas. Supongo que el cliché es el típico "a las mujeres les molesta que otra tenga el mismo vestido, mientras que a los hombres les da igual".

En el mundo anglosajón dos hombres que llevasen la misma camisa podrían exclamar:

> Twinsies!

Que podría traducirse como "gemelitos", queriendo decir "vamos vestidos iguales" o "tenemos algo en común".

Según esta entrada [del diccionario de Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/twinsies), que resalta que el término se usa con sentido humorístico, significa:

> Two people or things that are extremely similar, particularly in appearance.

Otras descripciones para el término serían:

> often used when posting a side-by-side picture of two friends who are dressed alike; also referenced when two people say or think the same thing at the same time.

que señala que se puede usar no solo cuando coincides en apariencia con otra persona, sino por ejemplo cuando dices lo mismo al mismo tiempo (como coincidir en "pensamiento").

¿Existe algún término o modismo en español que refleje de forma humorística que coincides con alguien en vestimenta como *twinsies*? Es decir, si un día llegas al trabajo y otra persona tiene la misma camisa o ropa que tú, ¿cómo dices, a modo de broma, "¡¡iguales!!"?

Comment: Soy hablante nativa de inglés, nunca he oído la palabra ‘twinsies’, me suena rarísima. Si se usa, me parece una palabra anticuada.

Comment: Pues ahí tienes el enlace al oxford dictionary. También puede buscar "twinsies" o "work/office twinsies" en google. [Office twinsies en facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Office-Twinsies-128972907218751/) y [work twinsies en twitter](https://twitter.com/worktwinsies?lang=en). Palabra "anticuada" o no, parece estar lejos de estar en desuso.

Answer (score 1):

En diferentes zonas vas a encontrar diferentes formas de llamarlas, probablemente usen alguna palabra local que sea equivalente a **gemelos** o alguna referencia cómica (como hacemos en Maracaibo, Venezuela). Podrías decir "gemelos", pero suena muy formal. En Venezuela diríamos "**morochos**"... pero, por lo menos en Maracaibo, lo asociaríamos con "Gaiteros" (cantantes y músicos que ejecutan gaita zuliana, una forma tradicional de música donde los ejecutantes normalmente lo hacen uniformados).

Así que podrías escuchar algo como "Hey.... tu morocho está del otro lado de la oficina, ¿no lo habéis visto?" (así, a la usanza castellana de hace como 1000 años). O, si los vemos uno al lado del otro, les preguntaríamos que cuándo o dónde es el próximo concierto del conjunto de gaitas.

Estoy seguro de que en otras zonas hacen exactamente lo mismo pero con palabras y asociaciones locales.

---

I'd say that in different areas people will probably tend to use some local word that is equivalent to twins *or* (as we usually do in Maracaibo, Venezuela) will come up with some funny/clever way to relate with other people that dress the same way. So... "Gemelos" is a possibility, but it's too formal, I think. So... in Venezuela: Morochos (that's "twins" in venezuela... then we derived it into "tripochos" for triplets). "Parecen morochos". "Hey, por ahí anda tu morocho en el otro lado de la oficina"... but, what we will do specifically in Maracaibo is mock the persons involved as if they were "gaiteros" (people who play "Gaita Zuliana", a traditional form of music and where all people normally dress in uniform to play). You see them standing next to each other and you ask them when or where the next Gaita concert will be. I'm sure in other places they pull the same trick but with different words and associations.